# Cannot execute command to specific column with gawk

Tags: text-processing, awk, newlines

I want to execute a specific command to the first column of the output of `wpa_cli scan_results`. This command, called it `mycmd` is taking a MAC address as input and returns the MAC and the OUI:

```
# ./mycmd AC:EE:9E:11:22:33 
AC:EE:9E:11:22:33   Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd
```

In order to change the first `wpa_cli scan_results` column, I run the following:

```
wpa_cli scan_results| sed 1d | gawk '{"./mycmd "$1| getline $1 }1'
```

This is however not replacing the first column with `mycmd` but delete the first column instead.

**Why do I have an empty column instead of the modified column with the OUI though my command work outside `gawk`?**

---

The script `mycmd` is the following:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cat ieee-oui.txt  | grep -i $(echo $1 | sed 's/://g' | grep -o '^......')
```

Comment: Does your ieee-oui.txt file have CRLF line endings? That would cause the field to _look_ empty even though it isn't. Try piping the output through `cat -v` or `sed -n l` (that's ell) or similar. Also FWIW you don't need to run five(!) commands for each input line; the 'awk way' is to first load key->text mapping into an awk array and then use something like `if(substr($1,1,6) in mapping) $1=mapping[substr($1,1,6)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the OUI file, it is a DOS file whose lines are CR-LF terminated. You must first translate it so that the lines are LF-terminated. So, either `dos2unix file`, or `tr -d '\r' < file > file2`, or edit the file with `vim` and `:set ff=unix`).

BTW, you should probably anchor your `grep` pattern. There are 6-digit postal codes in this OUI file that may inadvertently match your OUI.

Comment: Thanks. I simply added `sed 's/\r//g` at the end of `mycmd`: https://github.com/higher-security/wpa_cli-scan-with-oui.git